# Matrix.Reshape() function in Emgu CV

Tags: matrix, emgucv

Can anyone tell me about Matrix Reshape(int newChannels, int newRows) function. what is means the argument newChannels ?  My code below

```
Matrix<Double> A = new Matrix<Double>(4, 4);
Matrix<Double> reshapeMatrix;
reshapeMatrix = A.Reshape(1, 16);
```

this code works correctly . but

```
 reshapeMatrix = A.Reshape(2, 8);
```

this code run sucessfully but reshapeMatrix size is not correct and I cannot use reshapeMatrix data.

Can anyone explain why this happen? How i use reshape() function for any size matrix?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, Matrix.Reshape takes newChannels as first argument. A matrix can have several channels, for example color channels (1 for grayscale, 3 for RGB). What Reshape does is that it reshapes both channels, columns and rows of the matrix.

What you want to achieve with `reshapeMatrix = A.Reshape(2, 8);` is probably to reshape the matrix so that it has 2 columns and 8 rows, but still one color channel. Or am I wrong?

If that is what you want to achieve, the correct way to do it is:

```
reshapeMatrix = A.Reshape(1, 8);
```

As there are 16 elements and 8 rows, the number of columns will automatically be 2. The number of channels is still kept to one.

The reason why `reshapeMatrix = A.Reshape(1, 16);` works is because you specify that you should keep having one color channel. And with 16 rows, the only option left is to have one column.